# How do I set collapsed = FALSE for dashboardSidebar even on small screens with shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

shinydashboard allows you to set the dashboardSidebar as collapsed or not by default with the `collapsed` argument. This works on expected on normal sized screens, but not with small screens (e.g., on mobile). How would I get the menu to appear *not* collapsed when the page loads, even if the user is on a small screen?

The issue can be observed from the following MWE. Just zoom in on the page to see the dashboard collapse automatically (which is how the page renders normally on mobile):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE),
  dashboardBody(
    textOutput("res")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderText({
    if (input$sidebarCollapsed) {
      "Sidebar is collapsed"
    } else {
      "Sidebar is expanded"
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```